# Loading a conda environment in PyCharm - File or directory not found

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, conda

TLDR: PyCharm can't load my conda environment with a crypted error message:

`Error code 2. *path*: can't open the file 'info' [ErrNo 2] No such file or directory`

And does not list my conda environment in its run configuration.

I have a PyCharm Professional and Anaconda installation on Windows 11 and have created the conda environment using the shell, not with PyCharm.

Using the shell, I can run my Python code

```
conda activate fav-env
python mycode.py
```

Now I would much rather like to setup the interpreter in PyCharm to get rid of the red scribbly lines.
To do so, I click `Add Local Interpreter -> Conda Environment` and select the environment executable in
`C:\Users\myuser\anaconda3\envs\pythonproject\python.exe` (see image)

[image: PyCharm UI screenshot displaying the failed environment loading]

So far, PyCharm can detect the .exe. Once I click `Load Environments` it displays me the error message `Error code 2. *path*: can't open the file 'info' [ErrNo 2] No such file or directory` No idea why it would require a file 'info' when it asks me to open a Conda executable.

I tried a different way, by changing the `Run Configuration`. Here one can select the Python interpreter, including those from conda environments. Unfortunately, it only lists 2 out of 3 conda environments, the 1 out of 3 being the one that I would need in this project.
[image: PyCharm UI displaying the runtime configuratoin]

Comment: As it turns out, the conda environment uses a different version of Python than I had installed. I had to manually install the correct version of Python on my system, which made the conda environment show up on its own. And I had expected conda to take care of that for me, alas it did not.

Comment: Hi @Dustin, I'm facing the same issue, how do you mean "manually install the correct version of Python on my system". I have `3.11` on my system installed through `homebrew`, which is the one I used for the conda env. Can you help me out, please?

Comment: @DavidKunz if memory serves, the python version I had installed on my system was like 3.10, and the conda environment was using 3.9. I was hoping that conda would just give me an error à "install python 3.9 for this to work pls", or just install python 3.9 on its own, but it did neither. So when I manually installed 3.9, it worked. I don't really know homebrew thingies, but your error sounds a bit different, since you have twice the same python. Maybe you need to check if your python can be found in the env variables in PATH?